# Why does != work and just = doesn't?

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
  if (document.getElementById("hiddenButton").style.visibility != "visible") {
     document.getElementById("hiddenButton").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  else {
     document.getElementById("hiddenButton").style.visibility = "hidden";

  }
```

This code shows and hide a HTML button when you click on another button.

But my question is why does that code work and this doesn't:

```
  if (document.getElementById("hiddenButton").style.visibility = "hidden") {
     document.getElementById("hiddenButton").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  else {
     document.getElementById("hiddenButton").style.visibility = "hidden";

  }
```

Comment: because comparism is done with `==` and not only with one `=`

Comment: == <-- That is the equality operator in javascript

Comment: Because = is an assignment not a comparison, you probably want == (or ===, I'm not a javascript programmer so not entirely sure which but it's one of those)

Comment: @jbabey: Not really; OP is using assignment, not wondering why `('false'===false) == false`.

Comment: This is why we don't use the word `equals` when we talk about assigning a variable.  When we assign a value to a variable or object, we should be using the terminology `gets`.  So if I were to say `var myVar = 'this'` out loud it would sound like `"var myVar gets this"`  ...  And if I were testing a condition I would use the terminology `"if myVar is equal to this"`  --  Learning to separate the two colloquially helps in remembering what those differences are.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your condition is actually an assignment:

```
if (document.getElementById("hiddenButton").style.visibility = "hidden") {
```

You should be using `==`:

```
if (document.getElementById("hiddenButton").style.visibility == "hidden") {
```

Comment: Of course, how stupid of me. But when I do that it still doesn't work the first time I press the button, nothing happens. But when I press it the second time it works. When I use != I don't have that problem, any idea why?

Comment: Also worth noting that the if() is satisfied as truthy as the assignment returns the assigned value which is what's being evaluated

Comment: @user2100788 Probably because the first time you click, the `style.visibility` property is empty?

Comment: Yep, if it is empty it does not equal to visible, it is undefined.

Comment: @Jack Yes that was the problem, if I use === and put "visible" under else instead of "hidden" it works.

Answer (score 10):

The `=` is an assignment operation.

The `!=` is an inequality operator.

The `==` is an equality operator.

I guess what you need is the `==` operator. So replace your code with:

```
if (document.getElementById("hiddenButton").style.visibility == "hidden") {
```

Comment: **Seriously?** I fail to see how sarcasm helps the user solve his problem.  Just my opinion, but he probably wouldn't have asked the question if he wasn't *serious* ...

Comment: @Zak Agreed. Removed the sarcasm part. :)

Comment: The "!=" is not the not operator, it's the inequality operator. Big difference :)

Comment: @Jack Updated. Thanks for notifying. :) Was too binary! :P

Answer (score 6):

[JS Comparison operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

```
==      is equal to 
===     is exactly equal to (value and type)
!=      is not equal
```

For example:

```
var x = 1;  //define and assigned and now x equal to 1
x = 3;        //now x equal to 3

if( x == 4) {
    //you won't see this alert
    alert('Hello, x is 4 now');
} else {
    //you will see this alert
    alert('Hello, x hasn not been changed and it is still ' + x.toString());
}
```

Comment: for example's sake, `'1'==1` is **true**, but `'1'===1` is **false** (number and string compared, both have same value but different types).

Comment: @BradChristie: precisely ! and thank you for removing single quotes.

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is that you are confusing the assignment operator ( = ) with the equality operator ( == or ===). the assignment operator set the left hand side equal to whatever is on the right hand side, and the equality operator ( == or === ) actually tests for equality.

Answer (score 3):

It's because simple "=" is not for comparaison. Use "==" instead.

Answer (score 2):

`Left = Right`

This means, "Whatever the right side is, put it as the value for the left side."

All comparisons and other checks are done with two symbols to limit ambiguity and improper variable assignments when you simply meant to check a value.

```
!= means not equal to
== means equal
=== means equal and same object/datatype
= means "Assign the right side (Or what it evaluates to) to the variable on the left
```